# Configure keystore in JAVA_OPTS of manifest.yml in Could Foundry PCF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I need to configure keystore.jks file in manifest.yml using JAVA_OPTS .
keystore.jks file is present inside /resources of spring-boot application.

I am giving the keystore.jks path as below but its not getting picked up when deployed to PCF

```
env:
    JAVA_OPTS: '-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=classpath:resources/keystore.jks'
```

It's certain that I am not giving the path correctly.

Please suggest how to give path of a file in manifest.yml in PCF correctly .

Comment: When I set the path programmatically using System.setProperty it works but configuring in manifest.yml doesn't work.

Comment: `classpath:` isn't a valid path (that's a Spring specific convention, the JVM doesn't understand it). If you're going to set the keystore you need to give it a full or relative path. On Cloud Foundry, you can use `/app` or `/home/vcap/app` (the former is a symlink to the latter) as the path to the root of your application.